# How to determine who is using/modifying file in VisualSVN?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2015, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

Recently I have intalled VisualSVN and TortoiseSVN extensions in my Visual Studio 2015. I have successfully configured Repository and now it is working fine.

I have also configured `svn:needs-lock` property to my pages. Now, I need to know who is modifying or using the particular file and which is supposed to be committed.

The problem is that there may be multiple developers might be modifying multiple files and Now, I need a list of files which is exclusively checked out by developers. Just like a **Pending Changes Explorer in Visual Studio**  for whole repository. So, where can I get a list of files which are being used same as Visual Source Safe Control?

If you need any information just ask me in comment I will add it.

Thanks!!